# Using SMTP in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, smtp

I am having problems with sending an email using SMTP, it says "waiting for local host" then eventually times out.

My assumption is that SMTP is disabled on local host, so I had a look at the directions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx But none of the steps were applicable to my computer (Windows 8, asp.net 4, VS 2012)

Is this enabled by default and the problem is my code?
Here is my code

```
protected void SendMail()
{

    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
    email.To.Add(new MailAddress("removed"));
    email.Subject = "Contact Form";
    email.From = new MailAddress(emailTextbox.Text);
    email.Body = "From: " + nameTextbox.Text + "<br />";
    email.Body = "Message: " + commentTextbox.Text + "<br />"; 

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 465;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("removed", "removed");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(email);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SendMail();
        messageLabel.Text = "Thanks for your email, we will get back to you shortly.";
    }
    catch (Exception error) {
        messageLabel.Text = "Error " + error;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, really strange, where do you see "waiting for localhost"? your code does not call to localhost in any place, it should call to smtp.gmail.com directly... Maybe do you have a proxy configured in your machine?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see, it's asp, didn't noticed, hehe.

Comment: What exception exactly do you get?

Comment: can you please check your localhost/iis server *SMTP E-mail* settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please see, if adding following configuration helps:

```
 smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```